# Spark-submit can not find class (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java, apache-spark, jar

I try to run the Main class in my folder using the following code in the script:

```
spark-shell --class com.navercorp.Main /target/node2vec-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --cmd node2vec  ../graph/karate.edgelist --output ../walk/walk.txt
```

But it raises the error:

```
19/07/05 14:39:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/07/05 14:39:20 WARN deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load com.navercorp.Main.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.navercorp.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:810)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have jar file in my folder, this is the structure:
[image]

Also, I attach the structure of jar file:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
log4j2.properties
com/
com/navercorp/
com/navercorp/Node2vec$.class
com/navercorp/Main$Params$$typecreator1$1.class
com/navercorp/Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$11.class
com/navercorp/Word2vec$.class
com/navercorp/Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$8.class
com/navercorp/Node2vec$$anonfun$randomWalk$1$$anonfun$8.class
com/navercorp/Node2vec$$anonfun$indexingGraph$4.class
com/navercorp/Node2vec$$anonfun$initTransitionProb$1.class
com/navercorp/Main$.class
com/navercorp/Node2vec$$anonfun$loadNode2Id$1.class
com/navercorp/Node2vec$$anonfun$14.class
com/navercorp/Node2vec$$anonfun$readIndexedGraph$2$$anonfun$1.class
```

Could someone give me the advice to connect Main class?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I think you're accidentally using an absolute path for your .jar file when you intend to use a relative path.

Try
`spark-shell --class com.navercorp.Main target/node2vec-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --cmd node2vec  ../graph/karate.edgelist --output ../walk/walk.txt`

instead of `spark-shell --class com.navercorp.Main /target/node2vec-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --cmd node2vec  ../graph/karate.edgelist --output ../walk/walk.txt`

Comment: if it raises the same error, use the full path to the jar wherever it is. spark-submit cannot find your jar, that's the one and only reason

Answer (score 0):

Can you please look at the link below for a reference check:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications